# Api аутентификация на symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

Пытаюсь сделать REST API сервис на symfony(без использования api platform). Дошел до  аутентификации пользователя. Я правильно понимаю алгоритм работы,

```
1) Проходим обычную аутентификацию 
2) Создаем apiKey и записываем его в бд
3) Возвращаем клиенту этот apiKey
4) При каждом обращении клиента к серверу проверяем валидность apiKey
```

?

Если да, то как это все правильно сделать? Какие сервисы использовать и т.д. начиная с первого шага. Желательно использовать минимум сторонних сервисов, а только то что рекомендовано самими разработчиками symfony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) устанавливаете компонент безопасности `composer require symfony/security-bundle`

2) расширяете класс пользователя от интерфейса пользователя

```
UserEntity extends Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface UserInterface
```

Сущность пользователя должна содержать свойство apiToken

3) в файле `config/packages/security.yaml` добавляете сроки

```
    providers:
        user:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\UserEntity
                property: email
```

4) подразумевается, что у вас есть репозиторий для класса пользователя

5) создаем аутефикатор, добавляем в конструктор репозиторий

```
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken;

class ApiTokenAuthenticator implements AuthenticatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $userRepo;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepo)
    {
        $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Authentication Required'], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return $request->headers->has('TOKEN');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return $request->headers->get('TOKEN');
    }

    public function getUser($token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider): ?UserInterface
    {
        return $this->userRepo->getByToken($token);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): Response
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function createAuthenticatedToken(UserInterface $user, $providerKey)
    {
        return new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($user, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    }
```

Я не буду расписывать работу каждого метода, все описания можно почитать в интерфейсе

6) далее идем в `config/packages/security.yaml` и добавляем (меняем) строки

```
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: user
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\ApiTokenAuthenticator
```

и чуть ниже:

```
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, methods: [OPTIONS], roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user, methods: [GET, POST], roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Далее все запросы к `/user` вы делаете с заголовком TOKEN,

Сразу скажу, что аутенфикатор необходимо поправить по красоте, например в методе getUser, лучше сразу выбрасывать ошибку 403.

Comment: В дополнение https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html